# How to print a decimal into a 32 binary separating it 8 bits

Tags: c, binary, printf, bit, unsigned

I am trying to print a 32 binary integer with 8 bits separated by a space. ex (00000000 00000000) Then the result should be used for future testing which I will integrate 512 for example as y.

```
  #define CHAR_BITS 8

void displayBits(unsigned int n){


int sup = CHAR_BITS*sizeof(int);
while(sup >= 0)
{
    if(n & (((long int)1) << sup) )
        printf("1");
    else
        printf("0");
    sup--;


}
printf("\n");

return;
}
```

Comment: Can you try and rephrase the question? That doesn't really convey what you're trying to do. Maybe express in terms of desired output.

Comment: my code what it does it prints 32binary like 00000000000000000000000.... instead i want it to be printed with spaces every eight 0's

Comment: If code needs to "print a 32 binary integer" than use `(u)int32_t` rather than `int` and avoiding _assuming_ `int` is 32-bit.

Comment: regarding: `if(n & (((long int)1) << sup) )` this has the potental to result in undefined behavior.  when shifting a 1, use `unsigned int' or `long unsigned int`, not `long int`

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a working loop that prints out a single character at every loop iteration, and `i` is the loop index, beginning at 0, then the following conditional will add a space every 8 characters:

```
if(i && ((i + 1) % 8 == 0))
{
    putchar(' ');
}
```

However, your current code doesn't actually work correctly to produce the binary representation of an `int` either. Test it with the value 1 for `n` and examine its output. I see `100000000000000000000000000000001`.